# JIT SpaceTree visualization

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-4, infovis, thejit, space-tree

I need to use JIT SpaceTree into my project with MVC4.

Three models: `Symptom`, `Test`, `Reference`. 
Each has an `ID (guid)`, `Title`, `Links (List<Guid>)`.

A `Symptom` can link to either a `Test`, or a `Reference`. A `Test` can link to a `Symptom` or `Reference` and a `Reference` can only link to other `Refernces`.

On app start: Generate an `N` sized graph, random, assume 2-5 links from each node, follow the rules of linking, assume `N` is 1000.

How can I construct the JSON tree from these models?